# Java not using truststore

Tags: java, ssl, java-8, ssl-certificate, truststore

I am creating a HTTPS client for a REST API in java and there are some issues that I could not get around in a good way

A few things to note:

1. Server is using a self-signed certificate (it maybe that in some environment the customer may sign it with a trusted authority)
2. I have downloaded the root certificate from server and added to `truststore` using `keytool` command
3. I am setting the system property as  `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", path);`
4. I can list the server certificate to verify that its correctly imported and available to my client like:

   ```
   String filename = path_to_truststore;
   FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename);
   KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
   String password = "changeit";
   keystore.load(is, password.toCharArray());

   // This class retrieves the most-trusted CAs from the keystore
   PKIXParameters params = new PKIXParameters(keystore);

   // Get the set of trust anchors, which contain the most-trusted CA certificates
   Iterator it = params.getTrustAnchors().iterator();
   while (it.hasNext()) {
       TrustAnchor ta = (TrustAnchor) it.next();
       // Get certificate
       X509Certificate cert = ta.getTrustedCert();
       if (cert.getIssuerDN().getName().contains(server_cert_CN)) {
           System.out.println(cert.toString());
       }
   }
   ```
5. The server certificate does not have IP address in alternative subject names so I am using a custom `HostnameVerifier` to mitigate that issue which is working fine

After that, I am creating a URL object and getting connection like:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

But I am consistently getting error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I have tried to use my own trust store. I have tried to create my own SSLSocketFactory from the truststore but not luck.

The only way I can move past above error for now is to use a Trust all certificate `TrustManager` which I would really like to avoid.

I also tried to get some debug level logging from SSL etc using property:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl,handshake,trustmanager");
```

But I dont get any output other then the exception above.

Any help or idea would be welcome. I am using java 1.8

**Update**

Code that I use for creating SSLContext as per request by Felix

```
private SSLContext getSSLContext(File certificatePath) throws CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException, IOException {
        if (sslContext == null) {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(certificatePath);

            X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(inputStream);

            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry(Integer.toString(1), certificate);

            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);

            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

            context.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);  
            
            // Setting the context above with create TrustManager does not work. 
            // An accept all trust manager as below works.
            // context.init(null, getSelfSignedTrustManager(), null);

            sslContext = context;
        }
        return sslContext;
    }
```

Later, I set the context before creating any connection like:

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

Comment: have you tried -Djavax.net.debug=all just in case?

Comment: I remember that I also had to deal with some exceptions like this when we recently had to work with SSL sockets and self-signed certificates in Java. Maybe, the source code on [https://github.com/felix-seifert/network-programming/tree/main/task-4-encrypted-sockets-ssl-socket](https://github.com/felix-seifert/network-programming/tree/main/task-4-encrypted-sockets-ssl-socket) gives you some ideas on how to solve your issue.

Comment: @FelixSeifert This seems like only the server side. I am writing just the client for an already existing REST interface that I cannot influence.

Comment: That is why I linked this project: Besides the client side, it also simulates a client. Have a look at this file [https://github.com/felix-seifert/network-programming/blob/main/task-4-encrypted-sockets-ssl-socket/src/main/java/ConnectionSimulation.java](https://github.com/felix-seifert/network-programming/blob/main/task-4-encrypted-sockets-ssl-socket/src/main/java/ConnectionSimulation.java).

Comment: @FelixSeifert Got it, tried it but still getting same error. The certificate is loaded correctly, but still getting the error

Comment: @Carlos didnt help. Getting no output

Comment: What di you try? Can you maybe add some code of what you tried? When I have a look at what you posted, you have the certificate at the client side but you do not use them. I created an `SSLContext` which I then assigned to a new `HttpClient`. This client then performed the request.

Comment: @FelixSeifert Question updated with code that I used

Answer (score 0):

You need to install it as a trusted server. If it's signed by a non-trusted CA, you'll have to install CA's certificate too.

Comment: How can I do that? I don't have any influence over server, I can only write the client.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the file shown in the [GitHub repo in my comment](https://github.com/felix-seifert/network-programming/blob/main/task-4-encrypted-sockets-ssl-socket/src/main/java/ConnectionSimulation.java), I selected the relevant parts and showed them below. This example uses the `SslContext` which you created and sets it for the client.

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()      // Type java.net.http.HttpClient
        .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)    // Change to needed HTTP version
        .sslContext(getSSLContext(filePath))     // Function from above
        .build();

String[] headerArray = {
        "Accept", "text/html",
        "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) " +
                "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 " + 
                "Safari/537.36"};                // Extend header if needed

HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()   // Type java.net.http.HttpRequest
        .uri(uri)                                // URI of type java.net.URI
        .headers(headerArray)
        .GET()
        .build();

HttpResponse<String> response = null;            // Type java.net.http.HttpResponse
try {
    response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```